# Custom Fields - Boolean Display of True/False to Yes/No

Tags: php, wordpress

I am importing fields from a Real Estate site.

The Import of one Custom Field looks like this...

Field Name after Import ---> assistedLiving
Field Value             ---> false

to output the display in wordpress i use this...

```
<?php 
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;

    if ($immopress_property['assistedLiving']): ?>
        <li class="assistedLiving">
            <span class="attribute"  style="width:200px;display:block;float:left;"><?php echo 'Seniorengerechtes Wohnen' ; ?><span class="wpp_colon">:</span></span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving' , true); ?>&nbsp;</span>
        </li>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The Result on Site looks so...

```
**Seniorengerechtes Wohnen:false**
```

**How can i display False/True Values to display Yes/No or in German Ja/NEIN?**

The Funktion to display all Field (Display it Right with yes/no):

```
function immopress_the_fields( $args ) {

    global $post, $ImmoPress;

    extract( wp_parse_args( $args, array (
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'exclude' => $exclude,
        'echo' => TRUE
    ) ), EXTR_SKIP );

    $fields = immopress_get_fields( $args );

    if ( !$fields ) 
        return false;

    $output = '';

    $output .= '<ul class="immopress-fields">';

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $value) {

        $entry = $ImmoPress->values[$value];
        if ( $entry == '') 
            $entry = $value;

        $output .= "<li class='immopress-field-$key'>";
        $output .= "<strong class='immopress-key'>{$ImmoPress->fields[$key]}: </strong>";
        $output .= "<span class='immopress-value'>$entry</span>";
        $output .= "</li>"; 
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    if ( $echo ) {
        echo $output;
    } else {
        return $output;
    }
```

**But i need to display only Single Name & Values not all importet fields.**

Code for the Shortcode..

```
function immopress_fields_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $args = wp_parse_args( $atts, array (
        'echo' => FALSE
    ) );

    return immopress_the_fields( $args );       
}
add_shortcode( 'immopress_fields', 'immopress_fields_shortcode' );
```

Hope someone can Help me with that.

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if you simply use if / else statement like this:

```
<span class="value"><?php $assist=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving' , true); if ($assist=="") echo "keine Daten"; else if(strtolower($assist)=='true') echo "Ja"; else if(strtolower($assist)=='false') echo "Nein"; ?>&nbsp;</span>
```

**Note:**

For the code above to work,values for assistedLiving must use true/false and not 1 or 0.

**Update**

This is my first attempt at modifying shortcodes, so I'm not sure if it will work.

I'm also not sure if this is what you need:) - I modified it in a way so that you can specify a parameter **fieldname** and when used it should show only that field.

Change your shortcode function to this:

```
function immopress_fields_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $args = wp_parse_args( $atts, array (
        'echo' => FALSE,
        'fieldname' => ""
    ) );

    return immopress_the_fields( $args );       
}
add_shortcode( 'immopress_fields', 'immopress_fields_shortcode' );
```

In function immopress_the_fields() after

```
foreach ( $fields as $key => $value) {
```

add this:

```
if ($fieldname!="")//only look for a field when it is used in the shortcode
  if ($fieldname!=$key)//skip until you find the value in the shortcode 
    continue;
```

Not that this code is not efficient since $fields gets filled with all the fields all the time. Modified code is just a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want,sorry. If you have more problems not related to the original question create a new question instead of adding to the existing one.

Comment: It works but now the problem is that its always shown, also when the Custom Field dosent exist in that Post. Think the problem is the new <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving' , true)). Any idea ?

Comment: I updated the answer. It should now work for all three possibilities.

Comment: hi user850010, thank u but now dont show value data :(  But skip it when field not exist

Comment: i think the problem was (3x===) with == it seems to work. Thank u so much.   <span class="value"><?php $assist=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'builtInKitchen' , true); if ($assist=="") echo "keine Daten"; else if($assist==true) echo "Ja"; else if($assist==false) echo "Nein"; ?>&nbsp;</span>

Comment: I suggest to test it just to be sure. Put builtInKitchen to false on some post and see if it will show "Nein".

Comment: This is why === is needed. If assistedLiving does not exist it returns empty string "" and we need to check that with === to check if the returned value is a string type. What exactly does not work with ===?

Comment: Need to go now. will be back in a hour or so.

Comment: I updated the answer. Try now. Just be aware that the code assumes you are using true/false and not 1 or 0 for that meta key. I added a strtolower PHP function, so that it doesn't matter if true/false uses upper cases like TRUE/FalSE - damn PHP and his assumption about what is boolean true or false:)

Comment: sorry but the field dosent show up. Its true/false not 0/1. Dont know why.

Comment: Is there a other way to display the custom field ? When i use shortcode for all of them, it shows how it must. But cant customize it then. There are to much random in then and adding style to this is just like nightmare. Ill update the code above for the shortcode and display. Hope u have an idea....Thank You

Comment: Yeah I get your problem. What you probably want is to have some sort of shortcode as above but where you say which single field to display, and maybe even what html to show before the field, what html after the field in case you want to wrap it. If this is the case, I'm not that familiar with shortcodes so I cannot help you. You might try ask something like that in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry I was not able to help you more. Hope you will solve your issues.

Comment: I looked into shortocodes and updated the answer. Not sure if it works but the way I imagined it to work was so you can add a parameter to the shortcode named fieldname, so you would use it like [immopress_fields fieldname="assistedLiving"] and it would only show that field. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks...but this just implode all fields again :(

Comment: Strange. I added those two functions in my development site and just replaced code in immopress_get_fields( $args ); to fill an array with some values and the shortcode works. If I provide shortcode as [immopress_fields fieldname="field4"] I either get only that field or if field does not exist I do not get anything since it skipped every one of them, but using [immopress_fields] I get all the fields in the array.

Comment: This is the code I used - http://pastebin.com/6sgiY4bE - immopress_get_fields function is simplified but other two functions are not changed except for the added code in my answer.

Comment: I added this...         foreach ( $fields as $key => $value) {
if ($fieldname!="")//only look for a field when it is used in the shortcode
  if ($fieldname!=$key)//skip until you find the value in the shortcode
    continue;  and this...  'fieldname' => "" (to shortcode) and it works now. Thank u very very much ! U have spend much Time for this and helpt me a lot.

Comment: Yeah, that's me, when I find interesting problem, I just can't leave it alone:)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/) and then your code will be:

```
 <span class="value">
   {if get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving' , true)}
     Yah
   {else}
     NEIN
   {/if}
 </span>
```

To create this output:

```
<span class="value">Yah</span>
```